# Django cascade update by foreign key

Tags: django

I have a five models with a `is_delete` field in a each model.
What a right way cascade set this property `is_delete` for each child model if I set it in a parent model? 
I know that Django have  `ON_CASCADE` property field for `DELETE` method. 
But have the same method for `UPDATE`? 
I know about `signals` but may be another way? 
Thanks  a lot.

Comment: I don't get your question.

If you have a parent class (your parent model) and child classes inheriting from it, parent properties and methods should be mostly inherited in your child classes.

But it looks like you're trying to modify instances/db entries rather than classes/models.

Which one are you refering to?

Comment: No. I have 5 differents (not inherit) models. I don't right wrote about parent, sorry. Each model have a ForeignKey for a  "previous"  model. ModelA - ModelB(FK=ModelA) - ModelC(FK=ModelB) and etc.

Comment: So you'd like to implement an other deletion system where "deleted" data isn't removed from database but just tagged as "deleted"? (Assuming this `is_deleted` field is a `BooleanField`).

Comment: Exactly! Now I think about a signals and write a signal for each model. But I think there is a more right way. Thank you!

Comment: How are those foreignkeys named in your models?

Comment: It's named as the same model name in a lower case. For example,  `class Task: tasklist = FK(TaskList)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your own methods for your models.

I haven't tested this, but it could look like this :

```
class FooModel(models.Model):

    ...

    def alt_delete(self):
        for e in self.tracking_entries:
            e.alt_delete()
        self.is_delete = True
        self.save()

class BarModel(models.Model):

    ...
    foo = models.ForeignKey(FooModel, related_name="tracking_entries")

    def alt_delete(self):
        self.is_delete = True
        self.save()
```

Comment: Yes, this is  exactly what I find. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexBm1r42 Glad to hear that. You could also check mixins if you want to add a feature to a class without having to recode it every time.

If an answer satisfies you, you can as well upvote it. ;)

Comment: I'm small change the code:  I'm create Abstract class with blank method alt_delete() and save() method. In save I checked, if `self.is_delete` - call self.alt_delete. And in a each classes call objects for it FK and save it.